# Android MediaRecorder setOutPutFile() to stream using Socket

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-camera

I am developing an Android app that should be capable of streaming video to a local server on my network without storing it on SD card.

For this I have made simple socket application in C# that listens to the specific IP:PORT

On Android part, I had set the `setOutputFile()` to this IP:PORT using socket.

This application starts perfectly on Android phone but it does not display preview and when I start recording it exits without any exception. It also do not send any data stream to the network.

When I set the `setOutPutFile()` to SD card, it works perfectly and records video also.

For the server part, when I send the data from any other app (from PC) to the same IP:PORT, it receives the data.

In short, I want to establish the communication channel between PC and Android using socket for streaming.

**Here is my Android code:**

```
 Socket soc=new Socket("192.168.1.3",8210);
 ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(soc);
 ...
 ...
 // other Recorder setup steps
 ...
 ...
 Recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor()); // working fine for sdcard
 Recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
 Recorder.prepare();
```

**Here is my server app that is in C# and runs on PC:**

```
 socketForServer = new TcpClient("192.168.1.3", 8210);
 NetworkStream networkStream = socketForServer.GetStream();
 byte[] rData = new byte[1024];
 networkStream.Read(rData, 0, 1024);
 ...
 ...
 // process rData
 ...
 ...
```

I am not able to understand the problem that is occurring here. Am I going in right direction?

Comment: Hello Vinod, could you release the source code of the android app? I try to do the same thing, but the video freeze, and I don't know why... Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I can't release the code as it is from a commercial project. If you could send me your code, I will try to fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: I basically do the same thing than you, but I'm struggling on the format... I receive something, but without the good header I think. My problem is really well described here (http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system) but I dont know how to deal with.
Could you just show that small part?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Vinod, I am also facing a problem in recording. My server side is working fine but from my android client I am not able to send the data. So, if possible can you please provide some of sample source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was problem in my server code.

I had to use `TcpListener` in place of `TcpClient`.

Following is the correct code:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 8210);
Socket s = listener.AcceptSocket();
NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(s);
.
.
.
//reading the data from stream
.
.
.
```

Comment: Hi Vinod, I am trying to do the same but the .NET server side is not working fine in my case, any chance to get your working code?

Comment: @Giuseppe the code is now an IP so I can't share the code but if you could elaborate your problem then I can help.

Comment: So, you're able to stream from the Android MediaPlayer with the PFD -> FD by way of Socket?