# Stream video from Android to pc and use this in a application with live sensor data

Tags: android, flash, video, stream, flash-media-server

For this project i'm supposed to make a android app which stream video to my PC. At my PC i have to display this video stream and edit the size of the video (height and width) this according to sensor data (when a glass is full the video has to be displayed at full size, when a glass is empty the video has to be displayed at a small scale). I'm searching for options for flash (with FMS) but since it's a school project we don't have much budget. 
Should i use flash for this problem and is there maybe a demo for streaming from android to pc (flash or alternatives)?

Answer (score 0):

The demo for streaming from android to pc can been seen here:
http://tech2.in.com/how-to/android/how-to-stream-video-from-your-android-device-to-a-pc-and-vice-versa/239532

It uses VLC for streaming and source code is available.

Also checkout following post for related info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6933684/200272
[Streaming video from Android camera to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server)

Kind regards,
Bo

Comment: This is very cool and it works the only problem is that you cant play live video and youre bounded to vlc. Currently im watching into http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/ this is working but only in flowplayer..